# How to use two different global css for different page next js?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

I want to revamp my website, so want to create a different global css and can we use 2 diffrent global css with condition one for old page and second for new page

Comment: use this package to define css locally then you can export them and use it in any components https://styled-components.com/

Answer (score 0):

There is [an open issue for that](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/20546).

Currently you can only import global CSS for the whole app, or CSS in your coponents (directly in the component file, or with CSS modules).

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
import Link from "next/link";

export default () => (
  <div>

    <style jsx global>{`
      body {
        background-color: red;
      }
    `}</style>

    Hello, One!
    <Link href="/two">
      <a>Go to two</a>
    </Link>
  </div>
);
```